# How to fulfill React useEffect missing dependency requirements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-context, use-reducer

I can't figure out, how to fulfill the useEffect missing dependency requirements in the Dashboard component, where I only want to fetch Jobs once on render.
Adding fetchJobs as a dependency or removing the dependency array causes infinite re-renders.

***Dashboard.js:***

```
...
import { useGlobalContext } from "../context/appContext";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const { user, logout, fetchJobs } = useGlobalContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchJobs();
  }, []);

  return (
    ...
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

***appContext.js:***

```
...
const initialState = {
  user: null,
  jobs: []
};

const AppContext = React.createContext();

export const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  ...

  const fetchJobs = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await API.get(`/jobs`);
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_JOBS_SUCCESS, payload: data.jobs });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  ...

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...state,
        login,
        logout,
        fetchJobs
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};
```

I tried to implement it with useCallback, but that didn't work either.
Is this issue possibly related to using useContext?

I know that you can ignore the linting error by placing a `// eslint-disable-next-line` right above the dependency array, but that doesn't seem to be the right way to me.

Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-hamilton-ekftz3

Comment: A stupid solution is to have an `const [hasRun, setHasRun] = useState(false)` , in your `useEffect` do `if (!hasRun) {fetchJobs(); setHasRun(true);}` and set the dependencies to `[hasRun, fetchJobs]`. This should work without warnings and without comments to disable the linting. Anyway I believe what you are asking is impossible without a trick like this because React cannot know that `fetchJobs` redefinition doesn't matter... so it's a situation where the linter rule fails. You can work around this by making the effect run every time but do nothing after the first execution